# Insert numbered text on every even/odd line

Tags: vim, vi

In Vim I have the following text:

```
Door

Chair

Table

Uganda
```

And I want to add numbered text on every odd line, which should give this:

```
>item1
Door
>item2
Chair
>item3
Table
>item4
Uganda
```

Is this possible in vim?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. (What have you tried?)

Comment: This and it worked ;)  `:let i = 1 | g/^$/execute "normal i>item" . i | let i = i + 1`

Comment: I meant before you asked the question :-) By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I just asked if its possible before even doing an attempt. Very lazy don't you think? Anyway, it's nice if people come to this page after google'ing this question and can directly read the problem/answer without having to get confused by my lousy attempts :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this command which, as unintuitive as it sounds, increases `i` upon each match:

```
:let i = 1 | g/^$/execute "normal i>item" . i | let i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vimscript to do this:

```
:for s:i in range(1, line("$") / 2)
:  execute "normal " . eval(s:i * 2 - 1) . "gg"
:  execute "normal a" . ">item" . s:i
:endfor
```

- Loop over *half* of the lines in the file (since we only want the odd ones).
- Move to the appropriate line number (item number * 2 - 1 will give the next odd line) using `gg`.
- Append `>itemX` to the line, where X is the item number.

You can either input this directly on the vim command line, or place it in a file and then execute it using `:source <filename>`.

Alternatively, you can add this as a function to your .vimrc, and then execute it using `:call <funcname()>`.